# Как преобразовать + трансформировать массив в коллекцию?

Tags: javascript, es2016

Всем привет.
Есть такая разметка:

```js
let m = {
"status": true,
"data": {
  "init_data_for_index": [
    {
      "name": "Containertransport",
      "id": "1",
      "url": "containertransport",
      "image": "http:\/\/sunds.gmbh\/image\/index_center_menu_1.jpg",
      "description": "containertransport Das Unternehmen SEO GmbH erbringt Dienstleistungen im Bereich des Suchmaschinen-Marketings undder Internetseitenoptimierung."
    },
    {
      "name": "Kiepertransport",
      "id": "2",
      "url": "kiepertransport",
      "image": "http:\/\/sunds.gmbh\/image\/index_center_menu_2.jpg",
      "description": "kiepertransport, containertransport Die Vertragsparteien sind sich der Besonderheiten des Verlinkungswesens bewusst und vereinbaren im Sinne der gegenseitigen R\u00fccksichtnahme die nachfolgenden Allgemeinen Gesch\u00e4ftsbedingungen. "
    },
    {
      "name": "K\u00fchltransporte",
      "id": "3",
      "url": "kuehltransporte",
      "image": "http:\/\/sunds.gmbh\/image\/index_center_menu_3.jpg",
      "description": "kuehltransporte, containertransport Die nachfolgenden allgemeinen Gesch\u00e4ftsbedingungen. Das Unternehmen SEO GmbH erbringtDienstleistungen im Bereich des Suchmaschinen-Marketings und der Internetseitenoptimierung. Die Vertragsparteien sind sich der Besonderheiten des Verlinkungswesens bewusst und vereinbaren im Sinne der gegenseitigen R\u00fccksichtnahme die nachfolgenden Allgemeinen Gesch\u00e4ftsbedingungen."
    }
  ]
}};
```

Каким образом проще всего преобразовать эти данные к следующему виду:

```js
let z = {
"status": true,
"data": {
  "init_data_for_index": {
    "Containertransport": {
      "id": "1",
      "url": "containertransport",
      "image": "http:\/\/sunds.gmbh\/image\/index_center_menu_1.jpg",
      "description": "containertransport Das Unternehmen SEO GmbH erbringt Dienstleistungen im Bereich des Suchmaschinen-Marketings undder Internetseitenoptimierung."
    },
    "Kiepertransport": {
      "id": "2",
      "url": "kiepertransport",
      "image": "http:\/\/sunds.gmbh\/image\/index_center_menu_2.jpg",
      "description": "kiepertransport, containertransport Die Vertragsparteien sind sich der Besonderheiten des Verlinkungswesens bewusst und vereinbaren im Sinne der gegenseitigen R\u00fccksichtnahme die nachfolgenden Allgemeinen Gesch\u00e4ftsbedingungen. "
    },
    "K\u00fchltransporte": {
      "id": "3",
      "url": "kuehltransporte",
      "image": "http:\/\/sunds.gmbh\/image\/index_center_menu_3.jpg",
      "description": "kuehltransporte, containertransport Die nachfolgenden allgemeinen Gesch\u00e4ftsbedingungen. Das Unternehmen SEO GmbH erbringtDienstleistungen im Bereich des Suchmaschinen-Marketings und der Internetseitenoptimierung. Die Vertragsparteien sind sich der Besonderheiten des Verlinkungswesens bewusst und vereinbaren im Sinne der gegenseitigen R\u00fccksichtnahme die nachfolgenden Allgemeinen Gesch\u00e4ftsbedingungen."
    },
  }
 }
};
```

P.S. Буду благодарен за любую помощь, конструктивные советы или решения.

Comment: `m.data.init_data_for_index = m.data.init_data_for_index.reduce((acc, {name, ...val})=>({...acc, [name]: val}), {})`

Comment: Без бутылки будет не просто разобраться в данном решении )
Если у вас или у кого то еще будет решение по проще - буду рад его увидеть.

Comment: А вы можите написать как будет выглядеть вариант с редюсом в конкретно моем случае(c моими данными) ?  Что бы мне проще было разобраться как это работает.
Мне пока не совсем понятно какие аргументы я должен возвращать и где этот возврат я должен прописывать в вашей реализации релюса...

Comment: А сейчас разве не твои данные в варианте? :)

Comment: Дело в том, что если я запускаю конкретно ваш пример - я получаю вот такую ошибку:
http://joxi.ru/BA0QjX0IM6V1Qr

Comment: Потому что ты зачем-то дописал `()` в конце к моему коду

Comment: Понял. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Такой вопрос еще.
А если у меня в дополнение вторая разметка(нижний массив с данными) прилетает - которую надо обработать по аналогу с первой:
http://seo-gmbh.eu/json/api_sunds.php?action=init_data_for_activities_index
одним махом на лету и это - можно обработать теоретически(с помощью редюса)?

Comment: не понял вопроса - если там такой же массив - применяешь к нему ту же самую функцию и получаешь тот же результат

Comment: я имел ввиду что бы на лету сразу 2 эти массива обработать одновременно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98598/discussion-between-grundy-and-mike-kharkov).